# If a locally convergent power series factorises in $\Bbb{C}[[x,y]]$, then each factor is locally convergent

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I've just started reading through Miranda's "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces", and there's one small bit I can't seem to work out: it seems like it should be easy, and indeed the author says "It's an easy exercise." But I seem to be brain-dead at the moment. The statement:

"Let $f = xy + f_2+ f_3 + .... + f_n\in \Bbb{C}[[x,y]]  $ , with the $f_i$ the homogeneous polynomial components. Then in fact $f$ is just a polynomial, and $f$ has a factorisation in $\Bbb{C}[[x,y]]  $ as $ f = gh$ for $g, h$ formal power series, $g = x + g_2 + ...$, $h = y + h_2 + ...$. In this case, show that $h$ and $g$ have non-zero radii of convergence."

Somehow I've just no idea where to begin with this one. I first posted this question in a flawed form, but the statement as it is above seems to be pretty much as it is in the book.

Comment: What is $y$? That notation for $f$ is confusing. Why are there infinitely many $f_i$? Do you mean $f_ix^i$ in that sum?

Comment: Also, paraphrasing is dangerous when something confuses you - paraphrasing when you don't understand something is going to lead to miscommunication.

Comment: Also, it is hard to tell if you are given $g,h$, or proving it for all $g,h$ such that $gh=f$.

Comment: Ah, definitely meant the formal power series ring in two variables, not just one. Thank you. The fi are the homogeneous components. I think other than that it's quite clear.

Comment: A problem: Suppose $f=g_0h_0$ with say, $g_0$, $h_0$ having a non zero radius of convergence. Let $t(x,y)=1+\cdots$ any formal power series (so that $1/t(x,y)$ is also a formal power series), and $g(x,y)=t(x,y)g_0(x)$, $h(x,y)=h_0(x,y)/t(x,y)$. Then we have $f=gh$, but i doubt that for any power series $t$, $t(x,y)g_0(x,y)$ has a non zero radius of convergence. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: You're right Kelenner! Any unit in the formal power series ring, like $t$, will be a factor of any power series, including any convergent one. But $t$ need not be convergent. So the question's flawed.

Comment: Have edited the question - in the book $g$, $h$ were not units.